# Select from a set of similar-named tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple tables that have table-names ending with 'Event' word - like 'TcpEvent', 'RdpEvent', WebEvent', etc. The table schemas have few common columns like 'ID', 'Name', 'Date'.

Is there any generic SQL so that I can get all common-column content using a simple SINGLE select? I tried with following SQL - but it does not work.

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
      WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%Event') AS T) AS T;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please look up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1):

Create a view based on these tables and the columns they have in common:

```
create v_events as 
    select id, name, date, 'tcp' as eventtype from tcpEvent union all
    select id, name, date, 'rdp' as eventtype from rdpEvent union all
    select id, name, date, 'web' as eventtype from webEvent;
```

The alternative is to use dynamic SQL (via a `prepare` staetment).  Having a common view is probably the simplest, most maintainable method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL to achieve this, sample as following:(may this give you a hint)

```
declare @str varchar(max)
declare @str1 varchar(100)
set @str = 'select ID,Name from '
set @str1 = 'select ID,Name from '
select @str = @str +  TABLE_NAME + ' UNION ALL ' + @str1 FROM (SELECT Distinct TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
      WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%Event') A
IF CHARINDEX('UNION ALL',@str, 0) > 0
    SET @str = SUBSTRING(@str,0, len(@str)-len('UNION ALL select ID,Name from '))
print @str
```